# usb pendrive not working

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a problem with my usb pendrive, it isn't fully recognized in Windows, I can see the unit in my pc but I can't access it and unit dimension doesn't appear under it! If I open diskpart with pendrive plugged in it stays blocked, I can do nothing. I tried using ubuntu live, when I open gparted I get the error: "Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc" a lot of time, I've tried to create a new partition table but this failed

Comment: For anyone to have a reasonable chance of anwering this question.  You need to provide the errors you recieved.  Please edit your question and include this required information.

Comment: I've added the error I got on gparted

Comment: So you recived numerous I/O errors on `/dev/sdc`?  Do you know if the device is actually functional?  I/O errors indicate a hardware problem.

Comment: yeah I got a lot of errors like this, I just know that actually I can't access it in neither windows or linux

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.  A hardware problem that is indicating that the device is not operational.

Comment: Your pendrive apparently, and from your errors appears to be failing. It's a dead pendrive.